# What is this functional "pattern" called?

Tags: functional-programming, naming-conventions, nomenclature

I was fooling around with some functional programming when I came across the need for this function, however I don't know what this sort of thing is called in standard nomenclature.
Anyone recognizes it?

```
function WhatAmIDoing(args...)
   return function()
       return args
   end
end
```

**Edit:** generalized the function, it takes a variable amount of arguments ( or perhaps an implicit list) and returns a function that when invoked returns all the args, something like a curry or pickle, but it doesn't seem to be either.

Comment: I don't think I'd call it a pattern, any more than if statements are a pattern. A pattern usually solves a specific problem. This is just a pretty fundamental language construct. You just have a higher-order function that returns a closure.

Comment: What's the context? And how much of this code are we talking about? Is it just that the inner function is able to access variables defined in the outer? That's just a closure. Or is it that you're able to return nested functions? That's just a property of higher-order functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WhatAmIDoing is a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_order_function) because it is a function that returns another function.

The thing that it returns is a [thunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) — a closure created for delayed computation of the actual value.  Usually thunks are created to lazily evaluate an expression (and possibly memoize it), but in other cases, a function is simply needed in place of a bare value, as in the case of "`constantly 5`", which in some languages returns a function that always returns 5.

The latter might apply in the example given, because assuming the language evaluates in applicative-order (i.e. evaluates arguments before calling a function), the function serves no other purpose than to turn the values into a function that returns them.

WhatAmIDoing is really an implementation of the "constantly" function I was describing.  But in general, you don't have to return just `args` in the inner function.  You could return "`ackermann(args)`", which could take a long time, as in...

```
function WhatAmIDoing2(args...)
   return function()
       return ackermann(args)
   end
end
```

But WhatAmIDoing2 would return immediately because evaluation of the ackermann function would be suspended in a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)).  (Yes, even in a call-by-value language.)

Comment: This seems to be what's going on, something like "toThunk"

Comment: It's not really a thunk in a call-by-value language (is it?) since no computation would be delayed.

Answer (score 5):

In functional programming a function that takes another function as an argument or returns another function is called a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_order_function).

Answer (score 4):

I would say that XXXX returns a *closure* of the unnamed function bound on the values of x,y and z.

This [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) article may shed some light

Answer (score 2):

[Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is about transforming a function to a chain of functions, each taking only one parameter and returning another such function. So, this example has no relation to currying.

Pickling is a term ususally used to denote some kind of serialization. Maybe for storing a object built from multiple values.

If the aspect interesting to you is that the returned function can access the arguments of the XXXX function, then I would go with Remo.D.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). As you have "pattern" in your question, I thought I'd add that this feature of functional languages is often modelled using the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in languages without higher-order functions.

Answer (score 1):

Something very similar is called `constantly` in Clojure:

http://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/ab6fc90d56bfb3b969ed84058e1b3a4b30faa400/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1096

Only the function that `constantly` returns takes an arbitrary amount of arguments, making it more general (and flexible) than your pattern.

I don't know if this pattern has a name, but would use it in cases where normally functions are expected, but all I care for is that a certain value is returned:

```
(map (constantly 9) [1 2 3])
=> (9 9 9)
```

Just wondering, what do you use this for?

Comment: Yes I think the pattern (micro-pattern?)'constantly' is the right name for this. I didn't actually have any purpose for it, but when I was creating a functional library, as a learning experience, I muddled my way into the possibility of this and noticed it was kind of special and might have a proper name

Answer (score -2):

A delegate?

Basically you are returning a function?? or the output of a function?

Didn't understand, sorry...

Comment: This is not your usual C# thing. Functional programming is a different world altogether where functions return functions

Comment: Frederick is right, its not the usual stuff, but I don't know enough either to place a name on what I'm doing, although it seems like a useful thing to do

Comment: i think i need to start learning to read the tags before answering...
didn't know it was related to functional programming... so i assumed my language.