# What is a function that takes no arguments called?

Tags: language-agnostic, functional-programming, closures, nomenclature

Is there a term that describes a function that takes no arguments more concisely than "function that takes no arguments"? (In the same way that e.g. "higher order function" means "function that takes functions as arguments or returns a function")

I naturally think of "void", but I also think of side effects when I see "void". The situation I'm thinking of is the sort found in this discussion of `constantly`:

[What is this functional "pattern" called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442772/what-is-this-functional-pattern-called)

where you might create a closure that takes no arguments, has no side effects, but still does something interesting.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A nullary function, usually: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity

Whether a function has side-effects is orthogonal to how many arguments it has, so in a language where no function ever has side-effects, you don't need a more specific term. In languages with side-effects, I suppose you'd call it a "side-effect-free" or "pure" nullary function.

And then with (for example) memoization, a function can be logically pure even though you know that behind the scenes, it does have side-effects.

Comment: Hah! As is often the case when I get an answer here, I now feel like a total dork. Of couse I know "unary", "binary", etc., but didn't make the connection. stackoverflow is way better than Google (which I did start with) for situations like this!

Comment: I love that term "logically pure". Behind the scenes everything has side-effects and often people get fixated on removing impurity from every single conceivable deterministic function.

Answer (score 7):

A **nullary** or **niladic** function.

Answer (score 4):

A [Thunk?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_%28programming%29)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know "thunk" as another name for this. But "nullary" is the general term I was looking for.

Comment: That is, I should say I knew "thunk" in terms of delayed computation, but not as a synonym for "nullary".

Answer (score 0):

A constant

Apparently that’s too short an answer.